# How to Get Flickity Previous/Next Buttons to Work in Carousel

Tags: flickity, bigcartel

I'm using the "Setlist" theme on Big Cartel and I'm not sure how to enable the flickity arrows but I see it in the code at the bottom talking about a button

[image]

The reason I want the arrow/buttons is because on mobile the swipe motion is pretty buggy. You can check it out on my site shop.bbedits.com. It's either I fix the carousel or I disable vertical scrolling which I don't think is possible to do, only affecting the landing page.